# How to check if GIT has fully cloned a repository?

Tags: linux, git, bash

How can I check if git has successfully cloned a repository, and based on that result, execute commands inside the bash script?

I was trying some combinations of `grep` checking the output of `git status` but I've only managed to confuse myself more.

I'm ruining `timeout 60s git clone ...` so I must make sure the repository has cloned fully, and if it has not to skip whatever it would have done with the cloned data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture output from git command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715261/capture-output-from-git-command)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at it.

I think You are expecting this code.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13715406/2959196

Also Have a look at the conversation. It might help you better.

[How to detect if a git clone failed in a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13793836/2959196)

Answer (score 0):

Your timeout command will return a non zero exit code if it terminates the program. Use that rather than checking the repository to see if it's cloned.